# Where to place a file if it is getting accessed using ClassLoader.getSystemResource in WebApplication

Tags: java

I am using one third party jar in my code. In the jar file , in one of the classes, when I opened the class using de-compiler, the code below is written:

```
 java.net.URL fileURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("SOAPConfig.xml");
```

Now I am using this in my webapplication, where should I place this SOAPConfig.xml so that it will find the fileURL.

**Note**: I have tried putting this XML in WEB-INF/classes folder. But it is not working. Your help will be appreciated.

**In Addition:** In the explaination you have given, It is telling me not to use this code snippet inside the third party jar in this way...**What is the exact usage of this statement**

Comment: @skaffman Now is there any way out as I can't make changes in the third party jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassLoader.getSystemResource` will load the resource from the system classloader, which uses the classpath of the application as started from the command line. Any classloaders created by the application at runtime (i.e. the one that looks in `WEB-INF/classes`) are not on the system classpath.

You need to

1. Look through the script that starts your server, find out which directories are on the classpath there, and put your `SOAPConfig.xml` in one of those. If necessary, change the classpath in the script to look in a separate directory that's just used for your config file.
2. Track down the person who used `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` in the library, kick them squarely in the nuts, and tell them never to do that again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the beautiful explaination sir.

Comment: +1 Physical violence is an often overlooked tool in the programmers' arsenal.

Comment: @skaffman The explaination that you had given telling more towards -ve aspect of this statement..Please tell me where this statement should be used.